# Why is there a difference between invoking a method and returning a local variable?

Tags: java, testcase

fails at h.getNetYearlyIncome(), seems to be 5k too high. I have been working on it all day and cannot figure it out.

Why is h.getNetYearlyIncome()= h.getGrossYearlyIncome() - h.getTaxesWithheld()
not equal to yearlyIncome-taxesWitheld

```
public void testSalariedEmployeeMakingOver100K() {
SalariedEmployee h = new SalariedEmployeeImpl("John", "Doe", "Mechanical Turk", 1111, 9166.75);

    assertEquals(h.getFirstName(), "John");
    assertEquals(h.getLastName(), "Doe");
    assertEquals(h.getJobTitle(), "Mechanical Turk");
    assertEquals(h.getID(), 1111);
    assertEquals(h.getMonthlySalary(), 9166.75, 0.005);
    assertEquals(h.getGrossYearlyIncome(), 9166.75*12, 0.005);
    assertEquals(h.getTaxableIncome(), h.getGrossYearlyIncome(), 0.005);
    assertEquals(h.getTaxesWithheld(), 15000.25, 0.005);
    assertEquals(h.getNetYearlyIncome(), h.getGrossYearlyIncome()-h.getTaxesWithheld(), 0.005);
}




public class SalariedEmployeeImpl extends EmployeeImpl implements
    SalariedEmployee {
String first_name;
String last_name;
String job_title;
int id;
double monthly_salary = 0.0;
double yearlyIncome = 0.0;
double taxableIncome = 0.0;
double netIncome = 0.0;
double taxesWitheld = 0.0;
double over100k = 0.0;
double over50k= 0.0;

SalariedEmployeeImpl(String first_name, String last_name, String job_title,
        int id, double monthly_salary) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.last_name = last_name;
    this.job_title = job_title;
    this.id = id;
    this.monthly_salary = monthly_salary;
}

public String getFirstName() {

    return first_name;
}

public String getLastName() {

    return last_name;
}

public String getJobTitle() {

    return job_title;
}

public int getID() {

    return id;
}

public double getGrossYearlyIncome() {

    yearlyIncome = (monthly_salary * 12);

    return yearlyIncome;
}



public double getTaxableIncome() {

    taxableIncome = (monthly_salary*12);
    return taxableIncome;
}


    public double getTaxesWithheld() {

    double over100k = 0.0;
double over50k= 0.0;

    if(taxableIncome>100000.0){
        over100k = taxableIncome -100000.0;
        taxableIncome -=over100k;

    }
    if(taxableIncome >50000.0 && taxableIncome <=100000.0){
        over50k = taxableIncome-50000.0;
        taxableIncome -=over50k;


    }



        taxesWitheld = taxesWitheld + (.15 * over50k)+(.25 * over100k)+(.1*taxableIncome);

        return taxesWitheld ;
}
public double getNetYearlyIncome() {

    return yearlyIncome-taxesWitheld;
}
public double getMonthlySalary() {

    return monthly_salary;
}

public void setMonthlySalary(double salary) {
    this.monthly_salary = salary;

}
```

}

Comment: What @BheshGurung is saying is true, in that if you use a `double` to represent currency, you're going to get bitten by loss of precision or rounding at some point. However, it's not what's causing your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function `getGrossYearlyIncome` is not just a getter function—it initializes `yearlyIncome`. Until you call that function, `yearlyIncome` has value 0. However, `getNetYearlyIncome` uses `yearlyIncome` but does not call `getGrossYearlyIncome`, so `yearlyIncome` is not properly initialized when that is called first.

You have a similar problem with `getTaxableIncome` and `getTaxesWithheld`—they not only get a value but initialize member fields when called.

Comment: He calls `getGrossYearlyIncome` and `getTaxesWithheld` before that `assertEquals`. I think the issue is that he sets `taxesWithheld` using `taxesWithheld` so when he calls the function twice it produces a different value (i.e. `getTaxesWithheld` is not idempotent)

Comment: What is the proper fix exactly?

Comment: I don't quite understand the `getTaxesWithheld` function, but I think all you need to do (well, technically. I would strongly consider rewriting this code) is remove `taxesWithheld` from the right hand side of the assignment when you set it there. Why exactly is it there in the first place?

Comment: @Fish - There are several ways to fix this. I would recommend that you write a method that computes all dependent fields (looks like these are `yearlyIncome`, `taxesWithheld`, and `taxableIncome`). Call this method in the constructor and also as the last step within each `setWhatever` method. That way the internal state is always consistent and you can write the `get...` functions to simply return values (and not compute anything). Also, as @roliu points out, you need to redesign `getTaxesWithheld` so it returns the same value every time. (Perhaps another member field can help with this.)

Comment: Ted, you are the man. I took your advice and the testcases all come back green. Much appreciated